# A number $X$ is increased by $20\%$ to form a new number $Y$. $Y$ is then decreased by $20\%$ to form a third number $Z$. Express $Z$ in terms of $X$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A number $X$, is increased by $20\%$ to form a new number $Y$. $Y$ is then    decreased by $20\%$ to form a third number $Z$. Express $Z$ in terms of $X$?

Comment: note that $$0.2X\lt0.2Y$$

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, it's a bit ambiguous but $Y = 1.2X, Z = 0.8Y = 1.2\cdot0.8X = 0.96X$ is probably the answer on the questioners mind

Comment: I think the question has no meaning

Comment: What they're getting at is probably that multiplying by 0.8 is not the same as dividing by 1.2, it's a rather classical blooper even fairly advanced math students can make.

Comment: I don't know, if Y = 1.2 and then it was decreased to form Z by 20% then Z is 1 as 20%-X=1, the problem in this (Express Z in terms of X)